# Why is there a vacuum resistance

Tags: electrical-resistance, vacuum

My understanding of electrical resistance is, it arises due to the collision of the electrons with atoms in the path or in other words phonons. From the time of my undergrad years, I have been searching for a reason so as to explain why is there an electrical impedance of vacuum. I don't understand what provides this electrical impedance! There is no matter in vacuum to cause any collision. Also, the impedance is constant and does not have any dimensional part in it. That is confusing too.
Is the explanation connected to the finite energy of vacuum or something else related to quantum field theory?

Comment: I didn't see this question in suggestions. Thanks for directing me.

Comment: Explain *clearly*, why your question is not a dupe. If it is required, modify your question to make it really different. If you won't do it, your question will be mercilessly closed.

Comment: dude, i asked a question. what is wrong with you! stop being so mean